# API changes in Thunderbird 24

Tags: xul, gecko, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there a list of the breaking API changes in Thundebird 24? So it is possible to easier find incompatibilities in addons.

The difficulty is that error console does not show any error or warning, so it is quite hard to locate the bug caused by the change of API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same headache.

[**Error console)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Error_Console)

> The Error Console is deprecated in Firefox, and is now only made
>   available if you set the devtools.errorconsole.enabled preference to
>   true.

In TB: File->Preferences->Advanced->General->Config editor...

**Changes for TB 24**)

This is not so clear but i found only this [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Releases/24?redirect=no).

I hope these hits will help you and trust me, I really know how you feel. I also felt this frustration when I had to rewrite parts of my code 1 day before the planned release. :)